# .ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: \357\273\277host

Tags: git, github, ssh, config

I want to manage two GitHub accounts in a computer, a person, a company, but according to the online tutorial finished, suggesting that the "/c/Users/Gzb/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration error option: 357273277host
/c/Users/Gzb/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options ", that is configuration error, but did not find where the error, ask you advice. My.Ssh/config is written like this

```
Host compony.github.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host personal.github.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my`
```

Comment: You’ve saved a BOM in your `.ssh/config`. In your editor’s Save As dialog, select “UTF-8 without BOM” or something like that.

Comment: I tried, but there was $SSH -T git@compony.github.com
/c/Users/Gzb/.ssh/config:, line, 1:, Bad, configuration, option:, 357273277host
/c/Users/Gzb/.ssh/config:, terminating, 1, bad, configuration, options

Comment: Follow the instructions in the duplicate and overwrite your `.ssh/config` with a non-BOM version. Save it in Notepad as ASCII if you have to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made it